# Best practice for gem that creates its own database

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a gem that I want to be capable of creating its own database (and later making migrations to that database if necessary). The gem uses ActiveRecord when reading and writing to the database. Short of embedding my gem in a non-serving Rails application just to get the necessary rake tasks, is there a best practice or community-promoted method for doing this? Attaching a whole Rails infrastructure to my little command-line only app just to get future migration upgrades seems like way too much overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standalone_migrations gem to manage ActiveRecord environment outside of Rails: https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations. If you include your migrations or schema into a gem package, consumers of your gem can recreate db structure from scratch. I agree with robbrit that SQLite is the easiest choice for a database.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), which is a relatively lightweight ORM system (compared to ActiveRecord) in combination with an SQLite database. You don't need to use Rails for this, DataMapper drops nicely into a regular app, even something that isn't web-based.

Comment: Hi @robrit, thansk for your answer. I think I didn't explain my problem specifically enough. The issue isn't that I don't want to use ActiveRecord as my ORM (although I'm open to others), but I need something that will let me publish database schema creation/update scripts along with .

I would love to use AR migrations if possible, but it seems like doing so requires including all of the Rails rake tasks and loading the Rails environment in order to get the migration work to happen.

The migration part is important because I know the schema associated with this gem will change over time.

Comment: DataMapper is not ActiveRecord, it is a separate library that is similar to ActiveRecord, but doesn't require all the other bits like rake tasks, etc.